# How to create an open/close collectionView section

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` with number of cells under a header, nothing special.

The this is, that I want to make the collectionView to be openable and closable. When the view is loaded the section is closed, and when you tap on the header all of the cells will be shown (with a regular opening animation).

Does anybody have an idea how can I do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of different ways you can do this, but a simple way would be to keep track of what sections are expanded

```
var expandedSections = NSSet()
```

Then set up a gesture recognizer on your section header to tell you when it's been tapped. When a user taps a section you need two methods:

```
func sectionHeaderWasTapped(section: Int) {
    if self.expandedSections.contains(section) {
        self.expandedSections.removeObject(Int)
    }
    else {
        self.expandedSections.addObject(Int)
    }
    self.collectionView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: section))
}
```

then in numberOfItemsInSection do:

```
func numberOfItemsInSection(section: Int) {
    if self.expandedSections.contains(section) {
        return numberOfItemsInSection
    }
    else {
        return 0
    }
}
```

you can create helper methods to clean this up a bit. For example:

```
func toggleSectionExpanded(section: Int) {
    if self.expandedSections.contains(section) {
        self.expandedSections.removeObject(Int)
    }
    else {
        self.expandedSections.addObject(Int)
    }
    self.collectionView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: section))
}
```

and

```
func sectionIsExpanded(section:Int) {
    return self.expandedSections.contains(section)
}
```

if you want to clean things up a bit

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through insertion and deletion cells.

Use for this 
    `insertItemsAtIndexPaths` and `deleteItemsAtIndexPaths` methods in `performBatchUpdates` block like below:

```
[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^ {
    [datasource insertObject:OBJECT atIndex:INDEX];
    [self.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:@[INDEX_PATH]];
} completion:nil];
```

and

```
[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^ {
    [datasource removeItemAtIndex:INDEX_PATH];
    [self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[INDEX_PATH]];
} completion:nil];
```